# Why since Android 6 I can't delete a file located on a USB key with SAF?

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, storage-access-framework

I use SAF to access files on a USB key. Since Android 6 it is impossible to delete a file by the delete method of an object FileDocument. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [DocumentFile.html#delete()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#delete()). If that failed then please post  exception or error message.

Also, did you send Intent with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCMENT_TREE`?

Depending on which action you're using you'll need to request at least `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`, i.e.:

```
    intent.addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
```