# What is the use of Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION when requesting access to a folder using Storage access framework?

Tags: android, file, uri, storage-access-framework

When requesting access to a folder (document-tree) via StorageAccessFramework, we use this code. I got this code from [this repo](https://github.com/PavelBorze/SAF_sample) and also seen in other questions on StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109041/how-to-use-flag-grant-prefix-uri-permission-with-the-android-storage-access-fram) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310863/why-since-android-6-i-cant-delete-a-file-located-on-a-usb-key-with-saf).

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
    addFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
    )
}

startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
```

4 flags are added to the intent so that read/write permissions to the folder are given and also so that those permissions are persisted (across device restarts). My question is, what is the purpose of the `FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION` flag?

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION), this is what it does -

> When combined with FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and/or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION, the URI permission grant applies to any URI that is a prefix match against the original granted URI. (Without this flag, the URI must match exactly for access to be granted.) Another URI is considered a prefix match only when scheme, authority, and all path segments defined by the prefix are an exact match.

This leaves me with more questions than answers. Like what is a "prefix match" and what originally granted URI is the documentation referring to? Is this a flag which is useful when app requests permissions for a new folder?

Any clarification on this will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `addFlags()` call. None of those are for requesting content. Principally, they are for granting rights to others. For example, you might use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` in an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, as you are supplying content to another app and need to ensure that it has rights to read and/or write that content.

`FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION` are used to further describe the permission grant:

- Can we request that the permissions be saved by the system?
- Are those permissions just for the associated `Uri`, or is it for the `Uri` and any descendants (i.e., where the associated `Uri` is a prefix)